# C# assign const member with function

Tags: c#, java

in java its possible to do something like this

```
class {
    final int x = Random.randomInt();
    final int y = Random.randomInt();
}
```

...

```
switch (intVariable)
{
    case x: break;
    case y: break;
}
```

as long as generateInt is final, this compiles.

is there an equivalent in C#?

edit: you might ask why i dont use concrete values or enums, but i have my reasons why the values are be random. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

with [const](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx) you can't do that, it has to be a compile time constant.

You may use [readonly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), something like:

```
public class yourClass
    {
        public readonly int x = generateInt();

        public static int generateInt()
        {
            return DateTime.Now.Millisecond; // or any other method getSomeInt();
        }
    }
```

EDIT:
Since the question is now edited and asks with reference to case expression in switch statement. You can't specify a variable or readonly in the case statement, it has to be constant expression/compile time constant.

From [MSDN - Switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx)

> Each case label specifies a constant value.

You may use if...else for your scenario.

Comment: Although this is not the best example since `1` in the method is a compile time const.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, You are right, modified it to `DateTime.Now.Millisecond`

Comment: thanks, in my code this leads to the next issue, because i use those in a switch-case. `error CS0150: A constant value is expected`

Comment: @clamp, you have to use a compile time constant in case expression, you may resolve to using if..else, check the edited answer